# Storybook: The requested module XXX does not provide an export named XXX when trying to render complex components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I'm using Storybook for the first time. It mostly worked so far, but I am now getting an error that doesn't provide much information (given it seems to be wrong).

This is a component library I am trying to build
https://github.com/replyke/base

Which has 6 components that should be displayed with StoryBook.

4 of them display with no issues, but two of them (StatsBar & Comment) show the error on the title.

For both of these though, the error is that an interface is not being exported, but not for that component, but for a child component.

So for example, StatsBar which is giving me this error, is complaining that `The requested module '/src/components/AuthenticationModal/interface.ts' does not provide an export named 'AuthenticationModalProps'`

`AuthenticationModal` is a child component of `StatsBar`.
Same thing happens in the `Comment` component. It complains about the props of one of the child components.

When going to the Storybook "page" of either of these children btw, it renders just fine.